# How to debug on Google Chrome my React Native application running on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, google-chrome, debugging, react-native

I am a React Native newbie and I am trying to debug my application on Google Chrome since the XCode space is a bit noisy and my console.logs are hard to find.
My approach is to run the application from XCode to my iOS device, to open in Chrome http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui, to shake the device and to select "Debug JS Remotely". I get on the device the following error.
[image]

Comment: Try to change localhost:8081 in appdelegate.m to your machine's IP,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official doc: [Here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-on-a-device-with-chrome-developer-tools)

1. make sure your device and your desktop are using the same WIFI.
2. open the file `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m` and change "localhost" to the IP address of your computer
3. select "Debug JS Remotely" from the Developer Menu